# What is the best way to pipe JSON with whitespaces into a bash array?

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have JSON like this that I'm parsing with jq:

```
{
  "data": [
  {
    "item": {
       "name": "string 1"
    },
    "item": {
       "name": "string 2"
    },
    "item": {
       "name": "string 3"
    }
  }
  ]
}
```

...and I'm trying to get "string 1" "string 2" and "string 3" into a Bash array, but I can't find a solution that ignores the whitespace in them. Is there a method in jq that I'm missing, or perhaps an elegant solution in Bash for it?

Current method:

```
json_names=$(cat file.json | jq ".data[] .item .name")
read -a name_array <<< $json_names
```

Comment: The data you posted here is not a valid JSON

Comment: Sorry I edited the original post

Comment: Why can't you just have an array? `["string1", "string2", "string3"]`? That is valid JSON.

Comment: How do I get the items into that format though?

Comment: You edit `file.json` to have only that? Your latest edits are closer, but you are missing commas and JSON objects cannot contain duplicate keys (no more than one `"item"`)

Comment: Sorry the actual file is very large I was just trying to put a small example here

Comment: Sure -- we very much appreciate a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but the "C" in there means not just "Complete" but "Correct" -- the example has to **actually work**.

Comment: That's fine, but it will be almost impossible to extract elements from array values named `item1`, `item2`... `itemN`. You have an array, so there is no need for the numbered key values

Comment: Anyhow. Which version of bash? Is this 4.0+ so you have `readarray` / `mapfile`?

Comment: @cricket_007, ...not *that* impossible. `jq` is a pretty powerful language.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yeah, just formatting the data differently would make it cleaner :)

Comment: Bash version 3.2.57

Comment: @Jared, ...eww. You might consider using macports or homebrew to get a more modern bash release -- Apple is using ancient ones because they aren't willing to accept the GPLv3, but emphasis, *ancient*.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Just upgraded to 4.4.0

Comment: Good deal. If you want your scripts to use that new release (without being specific to the install location used by macports/homebrew/etc), use `#!/usr/bin/env bash` as your shebang and they'll honor the PATH when selecting an interpreter.

Answer (score 3):

The below assume your JSON text is in a string named `s`. That is:

```
s='{
  "data": [
  {
    "item1": {
       "name": "string 1"
    },
    "item2": {
       "name": "string 2"
    },
    "item3": {
       "name": "string 3"
    }
  }
  ]
}'
```

Unfortunately, both of the below will misbehave with strings containing literal newlines; since `jq` doesn't have support for NUL-delimited output, this is difficult to work around.

On bash 4 (with slightly sloppy error handling, but tersely):

```
readarray -t name_array < <(jq -r '.data[] | .[] | .name' <<<"$s")
```

...or on bash 3.x or newer (with very comprehensive error handling, but verbosely):

```
# -d '' tells read to process up to a NUL, and will exit with a nonzero exit status if that
# NUL is not seen; thus, this causes the read to pass through any error which occurred in
# jq.
IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a name_array \
  < <(jq -r '.data[] | .[] | .name' <<<"$s" && printf '\0')
```

---

This populates a bash array, contents of which can be displayed with:

```
declare -p name_array
```

Comment: Nicely done. You can simplify the `jq` command to `jq '.data[][].name'`. If embedded newlines are a concern, a workaround would be to omit the `-r` and later expand the array elements with `printf %b`.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are assigned in the form:

```
NAME=(VALUE1 VALUE2 ... )
```

where `NAME` is the name of the variable, `VALUE1`, `VALUE2`, and the rest are fields separated with characters that are present in the `$IFS` (input field separator) variable.

Since `jq` outputs the string values as lines (sequences separated with the new line character), then you can temporarily override `$IFS`, e.g.:

```
# Disable globbing, remember current -f flag value
[[ "$-" == *f* ]] || globbing_disabled=1
set -f

IFS=$'\n' a=( $(jq --raw-output '.data[].item.name' file.json) )

# Restore globbing
test -n "$globbing_disabled" && set +f
```

The above will create an array of three items for the following `file.json`:

```
{
  "data": [

    {"item": {
       "name": "string 1"
    }},
    {"item": {
       "name": "string 2"
    }},
    {"item": {
       "name": "string 3"
    }}
  ]
}
```

Comment: What if you have an entry named named `*`, or otherwise with a name that's expandable as a glob? (Which is to say that relying on field-splitting is not particularly good practice). Names such as `foo[1]` are not even particularly hypothetical, and if `nullglob` is enabled and no file named `foo1` exists in the current directory, the shell will expand that to nothing at all.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, you mean I should add `set -f`?

Comment: Or use `read`/`mapfile`/etc., since that way you aren't depending on modifications to global state. But yes, if you're going to stick with the field-splitting approach, `set -f`.

Answer (score 0):

The following shows how to create a bash array consisting of arbitrary JSON texts produced by a run of jq.

In the following, I'll assume input.json is a file with the following:

```
["string 1", "new\nline", {"x": 1}, ["one\ttab", 4]]
```

With this input, the jq filter `.[]` produces four JSON texts -- two JSON strings, a JSON object, and a JSON array.

The following bash script can then be used to set x to be a bash array of the JSON texts:

```
#!/bin/bash
x=()
while read -r value
do
  x+=("$value")
done < <(jq -c '.[]' input.json)
```

For example, adding this bash expression to the script:

```
for a in "${x[@]}" ; do echo a="$a"; done
```

would yield:

```
a="string 1"
a="new\nline"
a={"x":1}
a=["one\ttab",4]
```

Notice how (encoded) newlines and (encoded) tabs are handled properly.